# Migrating comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

Sometimes in response to a question/answer there is a long stream of comments which lead to another question. Right now there is no way to migrate comments to the new question. Perhaps such a feature would be useful.

Comment: Did you have a specific case in mind?

Comment: This question http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17633/medrash-breishis-rabsi-parshas-chaya-sara-231-which-lists-22-isha-ksheiras which came about from the answer to  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17629/why-was-chanah-called-an-ishah-kesheirah/17630#17630